# Linq outer join query

Tags: vb.net, linq

trying to join two datasets together using linq in vb. 
My first dataset has a list of all of the Accounts, and my second dataset has all of the accounts with balances.
I want to do a join that gets me all of the accounts, including the ones with balances.

Here's my code

```
Dim results = From a In accounts
                      Group Join ba In balanceAccounts On c.AccountId Equals a.AccountId Into Group
                      From p In Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      Select New With {.Name = a.Name, .Balance = ba.Balance


                                                               }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without join:

```
balanceAccounts
    .Select(x => new Result() { Name = x.Name, Balance = x.Balance })
    .Union(accounts.Select(x => new Result() { Name = x.Name, Balance = x.Balance }))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(x => x.First())
    .ToList();
```

Sorry for the c# ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, either change this

```
From p In Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

to

```
From ba In Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

or `.Balance = ba.Balance` to `.Balance = p.Balance`

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim results = From a In accounts
              Group Join ba In balanceAccounts On c.AccountId Equals a.AccountId Into Group
              From ba In Group.DefaultIfEmpty()
              Select New With 
              { .Name = a.Name, .Balance = ba.Balance }
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2008/01/31/converting-sql-to-linq-part-8-left-right-outer-join-bill-horst.aspx

HF